# How to get the X,Y,Z coordinates of a 3D object in matlab?

Tags: matlab, 3d, cursor, coordinates

I am working on a 3D object. My main goal is to click on the 3D object and save the X,Y,Z co-ordinates. I tried few programs, but most of them need the  datacursormode and then collect the co-ordinates using getCursorInfo. Is there any other way through which i can achieve my goal without using these? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want/can't you to use `datacursormode`?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I wanted to get it working the way getpts work. No specific reason. I just wanted to know if there is any other method available?

Comment: `getpts` does not give datapoints of an existing object, but gives coordinates specified with the mouse. How do you want to 'click' on a 3d-point on a 2d-screen? `getpts` in a 3d-environment does not give expected results at all. What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Matt- I am using surf function to view the object. When I click on the point, I would like to get the X,Y,Z coordinates of that point.